# Beginners Calculus Question: $\lim_{x\to 2}\frac {g(x)}{h(x)}$ when $\lim_{x\to 2} g(x) = -2$ and $\lim_{x\to -2}\lim h(x) =0$

Tags: calculus

Beginners Calculus Question: $\lim_{x\to2}\frac{g(x)}{h(x)}$  when $\lim_{x\to 2}g(x)=-2$ and $\lim_{x\to 2}h(x)=0$

How can one evaluate when the denominator is 0? Please remember that I am a calculus student.

Answer (score 0):

This limit doesn't exist.  The only way you can have a limit exist of a rational function when the denominator goes to 0 is if the numerator ALSO goes to 0.  In that case, we have what is called an indeterminant form,  for which you can either use algebra or L'hospital's rule to handle.

Here,  you don't have that.   Logically, what you have is the top is approaching 2, the bottom is approaching 0....as we take numbers close to 2, and divide them by numbers close to 0,  we get numbers that explode, either to positive or negative infinity...which don't approach any finite limit

Answer (score 0):

If you divide $f(x)$ by $g(x)$ the factors cancels out so that your limit might be finite else it is infinite.